# Qt QML/Quick component missing in Qt Designer

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qtquick2, qt-designer

I have created some Quick components, each in its individual `.qml` file and defined by a root Item object.

I would like to interact with those items through the Qt Designer in Qt Creator, in order to assemble my screens more easily.

However it only shows the `.qml` files from a folder that I created called `qml/`. It does not index sub directories such as `qml/misc/`, etc.

**Already tried**

1. Updated the environment variable QML_IMPORT_PATH and QML2_IMPORT_PATH in my .pro
2. Closed my project between QMake calls and reloaded the Designer

It only works if I place every `.qml` file inside the `qml/` folder

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this?